# Nvidia Tesla T4 tensor core benchmark

Tags: cuda, gpu, benchmarking, nvidia

I am using the code given [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/cudaTensorCoreGemm/cudaTensorCoreGemm.cu) to find out the TFlops of mixed precision ops on Nvidia Tesla T4. Its theoretical value is given 65 Tflops. however, the code produces the value as 10 Tflops. Any explanation that can justify this happening?

Comment: I don't think the CUDA Samples are meant as high-performance, highly optimised codes, that get anywhere close to the theoretical performance of a GPU. They are there to demonstrate concepts and provide a testing ground.

Comment: So any benchmarking code you can suggest for the purpose of testing the half-precision flops, int4, and int8 iops for the gpu? I have already tried using the code here [link](https://github.com/ekondis/mixbench). This gives peak Tflops as 15

Comment: I am speaking of the turing tensor cores capable of doing that...The numbers for the int4 and int8 iops are present here [link](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/tesla-t4/). you will find the info in the specs section once you scroll down

Comment: Asking how to max out the TFLOPs in a synthetic example (e.g. with a trivial memory access pattern to make sure that's not a bottleneck) is a separate question from explaining the performance of some example code.  Ask that separately if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be more of an extended comment, bet hear me out ...

As pointed out in the comments CUDA Samples are not meant as performance measuring tools.
The second benchmark you provided does not actually use tensor cores, but just a normal instruction executed on FP32 or FP64 cores.

```
for(int i=0; i<compute_iterations; i++){
            tmps[j] = mad(tmps[j], tmps[j], seed);
    }
```

On a Turing T4 this, for single precision operations gives me a peak of 7.97 TFLOPS, so very close to the theoretical limit of 8.1 TFLOPS.
For half precision operations I get 16.09 TFLOPS, as expected about double that of the single precision performance.

Now, on to Tensor cores. As the previously mentioned benchmark does not use them, let's look for something that does.
CUTLASS (https://github.com/NVIDIA/cutlass) is a high performance Matrix-Matrix Multiplication library from NVIDIA.
They provide a profiling application for all the kernels provided. If you run this on a T4, you should get output like this:

```
Problem ID: 1

   Provider: ^[[1;37mCUTLASS^[[0m
   OperationKind: ^[[1;37mgemm^[[0m
   Operation: cutlass_tensorop_h1688gemm_256x128_32x2_nt_align8

      Status: ^[[1;37mSuccess^[[0m
Verification: ^[[1;37mON^[[0m
 Disposition: ^[[1;32mPassed^[[0m

 reference_device: Passed
      cuBLAS: Passed

   Arguments: --gemm_kind=universal --m=1024 --n=1024 --k=1024 --A=f16:column --B=f16:row --C=f16:column --alpha=1  \
              --beta=0 --split_k_slices=1 --batch_count=1 --op_class=tensorop --accum=f16 --cta_m=256 --cta_n=128  \
              --cta_k=32 --stages=2 --warps_m=4 --warps_n=2 --warps_k=1 --inst_m=16 --inst_n=8 --inst_k=8 --min_cc=75  \
              --max_cc=1024

       Bytes: 6291456  bytes
       FLOPs: 2149580800  flops

     Runtime: 0.0640419  ms
      Memory: 91.4928 GiB/s

        Math: 33565.2 GFLOP/s
```

As you can see we are now actually using Tensor cores, and half-precision operation, with a performance of 33.5 TFLOPS. Now, this might not be at 65 TFLOS, but for an application you can use in the real world, that is pretty good.

Comment: I tried running the same script with kernel= cutlass_tensorop_h1688gemm_256x128_32x2_nt_align8 I am still not getting more than 16000 in result

Comment: are you sure you are running it with the same arguments? I just ran the entire profiler and picked out a result. If you don't achieve high enough occupancy, etc, it seems reasonable that you will not achieve anything near peak performance.

Comment: I had run the code with the same arguments. I tried again and it turns out that setting the clock to max did the trick! got about 40 TFLOPS...thanks for your help on this..much appreciated..